# what does "Detected assembler with broken .inst" mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, disassembly

While I try to install kernel from sources, I get

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:48: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable
```

I tried rebuilding bin-utils but the message won't go.

what is causing this message and how to fix it? I want to generate disassembly.

Answer (score 1):

That message was added in [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=bbb56c27228d4ad64aca858c5af49d0f2f11c645) commit. Judging from its commit message, you should use binutils newer than 2.25, which contains `gas` (assembler) with corresponding bugfix. So you should probably upgrade your ARM64 toolchain.